# Does using method chaining in PHP cause any problems with resources or memory?

Tags: php, oop, class, object, methods

I'm talking about methods like this:

```
    $object->method()->method1('param')->method2('param');
```

Those are created by returning the object in the function.

```
    return $this;
```

I've seen third-party software use that method, but I'm wondering, wouldn't that cause a bit of a problem with the resources or memory because you're continuously returning the entire object?

Comment: I think you mean "chained method calls", not nested methods.  And I'd suggest that you read up on references.

Comment: I edited the title to refer to "method chaining" instead of "nested methods".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not returning the entire object, but rather a *reference* to the object -- that is, just the memory location where it resides. So objects aren't constantly being copied around in memory when methods are called along the chain.

By default (*mainly, but read the link for actual details*), [objects in PHP are passed, returned, and assigned by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/language.oop5.references.php).

[See the PHP docs on references.](http://php.net/manual/language.references.php)

Comment: even stuff like strings are just passed around as memory addresses too. I believe numerics are always copied, but regardless they are small in byte values anyway so its similar to passing a memory address as far as how many bytes goes.

Answer (score 2):

Chaining methods by returning the object is actually efficient.

The stack does not grow bigger by adding new methods to the chain.

PHP also does not return a copy of the object but a reference, it does not pass the object but a "pointer".

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't "nested methods", but it's called [method chaining](http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1163-php5-method-chaining.html) and it shouldn't affect performance in anyway (your not going anyhow "deep in the stack").

You can split the code into those pieces:

```
$res = $object->method();
$res = $res->method1('param')
$res = $res->method2('param');
// and res is still equivalent to $object if you return $this
```

So no object copying, no nested calls, no many items in "call stack"... No performance overhead, you should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the PHP engine will not suffer if you chain method calls together, your IDE might and could possibly slow down as a result.  For example, PhpStorm doesn't like this particularly lengthy browser test and advises splitting it into shorter fragments.

[image]